# com.google.zxing.NotFoundException for all possibility to decode image containing barcode

Tags: android, zxing

i'm using zxing core and integrated with my android app which takes picture. I'm giving bitmap picture input to RGBLuminanceSource. But every time i'm getting NOTFoundException. I do not want to integrate with zxing barcode scanner via intents or CaptureActivity. Here is the code.

```
       Map<DecodeHintType,Object> HINTS;
       Map<DecodeHintType,Object> HINTS_PURE;
       HINTS = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType,Object>(DecodeHintType.class);
       HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
       HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
       HINTS_PURE = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType,Object>(HINTS);
       HINTS_PURE.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
       ImageView mImg;

       if (requestCode == SCANNER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
          // Bitmap bMap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        Bitmap bMap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(outputFileUri));


            // creating binary bitmap from source image


           int length=bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()*10;
           int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()]; 
           bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),                bMap.getHeight());

           //test view to display captured image 
           mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           mImg.setImageBitmap(bMap);


           // zxing decoding of bitmap image
           Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
           String msg=bMap.getWidth()+" * "+bMap.getHeight();
           Log.e("DEBUGGG", msg);
           LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(),intArray);


           BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));


           Collection<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>(1);
           ReaderException savedException = null;



           try {
                  // Look for multiple barcodes
                  MultipleBarcodeReader multiReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(reader);

                  Result[] theResults = multiReader.decodeMultiple(bitmap, HINTS);
                  if (theResults != null) {
                    results.addAll(Arrays.asList(theResults));
                  }
                } catch (ReaderException re) {
                    re.printStackTrace();
                  savedException = re;
                  re.printStackTrace();
                }


                if (results.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                      // Look for pure barcode
                      Result theResult = reader.decode(bitmap, HINTS_PURE);
                      if (theResult != null) {
                        results.add(theResult);
                      }
                    } catch (ReaderException re) {
                      savedException = re;
                      re.printStackTrace();

                    }
                  }

                  if (results.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                      // Look for normal barcode in photo
                      Result theResult = reader.decode(bitmap, HINTS);
                      if (theResult != null) {
                        results.add(theResult);
                      }
                    } catch (ReaderException re) {
                      savedException = re;
                      re.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }

                  if (results.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                      // Try again with other binarizer
                      BinaryBitmap hybridBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                      Result theResult = reader.decode(hybridBitmap, HINTS);
                      if (theResult != null) {
                        results.add(theResult);
                      }
                    } catch (ReaderException re) {
                      savedException = re;
                      re.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                String barcoderesult="";
                  for (Result result : results) {
                      barcoderesult=barcoderesult+result.getText();
                      Log.e("Debugger","code:  " +result.getText() );
                    }

                //result is empty and notfound exception in logs
```

Comment: Why not actually show the image you are decoding?

Comment: @Sean  here is the image.. http://s1.postimg.org/pim8l22yn/product.jpg

Comment: and barcode android app can read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create bitmap in rgb from inputstream using bitmap.config.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it decodes fine in general. The most likely answer is just that this particular image does not scan. Try one without shadow, maybe. It is also possible you are not parsing the image correctly. Try other images to verify

Comment: i tried different images and without shadow result is the same. even tried saving image to sdcard than reading and decoding. Any help?

Comment: Debug how you are reading the image then. For example your code suggests that you assume ARGB data but Android is YUV planar by default. You could be reading noise.

Comment: if i use                                          PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(byte[] yuvData, int dataWidth, int dataHeight, int left, int top,
      int width, int height, boolean reverseHorizontal)                              what could be possible values for left and top. can dataheight be the same as height? what about datawidth

Comment: First you need to confirm what you are reading before jumping to that. I don't know you're reading YUV, just suggesting that this points to a problem in the image perhaps.

Comment: i'm new to android.. using Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), saving png image in sdcard and reading back. guess it will be rgb

Comment: What was the answer? it would be useful to post here an accept it.